# node.js import/require cannot find custom module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Below is my project structure.

```
A
 /node_modules
 /src
   /custom
     /prod
        tests.js
```

I need to access axios present in the node_modules from tests.js. How do I access that? I tried below, but I still see

```
"Cannot find module ../../../axios"

var axiom = require('../../../axios')
```

Why does my declaration doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give full path. Just do:

```
var axios = require('axios');
```

If you haven't yet installed `axios`. You can do that by running following command:

```
npm install axios --save
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `{"errorMessage":"Cannot find module 'axios'","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)","Module.require (module.js:596:17)","require (internal/module.js:11:18)","Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/producer.js:1:75)","Module._compile (module.js:652:30)","Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)","Module.load (module.js:565:32)","tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)","Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"]}
`

Comment: What is the error now? and does your error says `axis` or `axios`?

Comment: Have you installed axios? I have updated the answer if it isn't installed.

Comment: yeah.. it is installed.